# Proxmox, nginx reverse proxy and multiple websites on different containers

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have trouble configuring SSL with reverse proxy.
What I have: Proxmox installed with 3 containers - 2 containers are with websites and 3rd  is a reverse proxy.

**Container 1**

- domain1.com
- domain2.com

**Container 2**

- domain3.com
- domain4.com

Public IP points to **Container 3** (which is a reverse proxy).

**How and "where" (on containers, on the reverse proxy, or on both) should I issue an SSL certificate? I want all of the domains to work only via HTTPS.**

Reverse proxy has the following configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain1.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass         http://192.168.4.100:80;# Container 1
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain2.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass         http://192.168.4.100:80;# Container 1
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain3.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass         http://192.168.4.200:80;# Container 2
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain4.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass         http://192.168.4.200:80;# Container 2
    }
}
```

**Update:** I am able to issue a domain certificate but to make everything work I have to put these certificates on BOTH containers: for reverse proxy and container with domain/website itself. I believe it's kind of dirty and hard to maintain. Please advise

Answer (score 0):

I would just add the SSL certificates to the reverse Proxy and use http to the internal web servers (containers)

Comment: In that case, my code of the website still thinks I'm on HTTP (because I used port 80). If I try to change to 443, Nginx (in a container) throws an error saying I need to add a certificate if I would like to use port 443.